# Class import in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, class, tkinter, import

Hello: I have a few questions:

1. in the Gallery module widget appears ok to me - 640x480, After import I have a small window, I do not understand why?
2. How do I move this imported widget to the center of the main window? After import relative to the main window, it appears in the upper right corner. I tried this code fact it can be set but the problem is that here appears a second empty window and this empty one I can operate.

old_code.py

```
def get_gallery(self):
    from GUI.module.gallery import Gallery
    Gallery(tk.Toplevel(self.root)).pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    x = self.root.winfo_x()
    y = self.root.winfo_y()
    tk.Toplevel(self.root).geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 600, y + 800))
```

3. How to make this imported window pasted into the main window after import? I.e. so that there are not two windows of the main window and the gallery (after import) but that they constitute one window? Thank you for your help :D

gallery.py

```
class Gallery(tk.Frame):

code of gallery
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.geometry("%dx%d" % (640, 480))
    root.title("Open file")
    app = Gallery(tk.Tk())
    root.mainloop()
```

main.py

```
... 
def get_gallery(self):
    from GUI.module.gallery import Gallery
    Gallery(tk.Toplevel(self.root)).pack()

def get_run_gallery(self):
    jpg = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Gallery", command=self.get_gallery)
    self.my_canvas.create_window(780, 220, anchor="nw", window=jpg, height=50, width=200)
...

def get_run_first_page():
    calling ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first = MainPage(tk.Tk())
    first.get_run_first_page()
```

Comment: In `old_code.py` in `get_gallery`, you create a new window and put the `Gallery` in it. After that you create another window and position it to `"+%d+%d" % (x + 600, y + 800)`. That doesn't look right.

Comment: I know, and it doesn't work. I'm just learning Tkinter and I'm stuck with it....

Comment: I tried to approach it like this    
        Gallery(tk.Toplevel(self.root).geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 600, y + 800)).pack()
But it doesn't work either....

Comment: Try `new_window = tk.Toplevel(self.root)`, `gallary = Gallery(new_window)`, `gallary.pack(fill="both", expand=True)`, `new_window.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x + 600, y + 800))`. Make sure that they are on separate lines. Also if you want to write better code read [this](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) - it's from python's official website.

Comment: Item 2 - works thank you VERY much. I still need to figure out point 1 and 3. I keep getting a small window open instead of 640x480.